# urgent: dapp wallet connect security issue

Tags: security, walletconnect

i just attempted to connect metamask wallet to dappshubconnect using my 12-word phrase. a qr code appeared and i sent it to someone posing as support for a project i'm invested in. How high is my risk right now and is there anything I can do to ensure my wallet security?

Comment: You should never give your private key/seed phrase to anyone, ever. If you have done so, create a new independent wallet a move everything to the new wallet, everything.

Answer (score 0):

There are many types of scam on the web, but social engineering tops the list of the most effective ones. Posing as a representative of a project/company you trust to gain something from you is a scam as old as time. DApps do not require your 12 word phrase (generally, only wallet providers need that key). You should never share that key with any entity you don't 100% trust, and by 100% I mean you would put a million dollars there with no hesitation.

While there is no way to know for sure if your wallet is at risk, it most likely is and the best option to protect your funds is to move them all to the new uncompromised wallet.

Comment: With most of the latest tokens all having tax on sell, but, and transfer transactions, you will most likely still lose part of your investment by moving it to the other wallet, but it still beats losing all of it in case the wallet is compromised.